# Javascript: Find corner positions of rectangle in 2d matrix (array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, matrix

I have an array like below...

```
var my_array = [
  '00000000000000000000000',
  '00000011111111000000000',
  '00000011111111000000000',
  '00000011111111000000000',
  '00000011111111000000000',
  '00000011111111000000000',
  '00000000000000000000000',
]
```

... and I'd like to get a function that is able to calculate the bounds (**4 corner positions**) of the **1-characters** in the array above.

So my result should be something like this:

```
var result= {
  'top-left' : [6,1],
  'bottom-left' : [6,5],
  'top-right' : [13,1],
  'bottom-right' : [13,5]
}
```

---

Also the function should be able to work on rotated arrays like the example array below:

```
var rotated_array = [
  "00000000000000000000000",
  "00000000001100000000000",
  "00000000111110000000000",
  "00000001111111000000000",
  "00000111111111100000000",
  "00000111111111000000000",
  "00000011111100000000000",
  "00000001110000000000000",
  "00000000100000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000000"
]

// array ----> result should be something like this:

var result= {
  'top-left' : [5,5],
  'bottom-left' : [8,8],
  'top-right' : [11,1],
  'bottom-right' : [14,4]
}
```

I've developed a function that is able to return an array of the '1'-characters-positions (x/y-positions) so I will get an result array (from `my_array`) like this:

```
var positions = [[7,2],[7,1],[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[7,5],[7,4],[7,3],[8,3],[8,2],[8,1],[9,1],[9,2],[9,3],[9,4],[9,5],[8,5],[8,4],[10,5],[10,4],[10,3],[10,2],[10,1],[11,1],[11,2],[11,3],[11,4],[11,5],[12,5],[12,4],[12,3],[12,2],[12,1],[13,1],[13,2],[13,3],[13,4],[13,5]]
```

Because the arraylist above includes all positions of my rectangle it also should includes the 4 corner positions... But how to get the right coordinates?

---

My idea was to filter the arrays biggest xValue, biggest yValue, smallest xValue and smallest yValue to get the 4 corners. Sound good, but there are also multiple possibilities for my corners:

```js
var positions = [[7,2],[7,1],[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[7,5],[7,4],[7,3],[8,3],[8,2],[8,1],[9,1],[9,2],[9,3],[9,4],[9,5],[8,5],[8,4],[10,5],[10,4],[10,3],[10,2],[10,1],[11,1],[11,2],[11,3],[11,4],[11,5],[12,5],[12,4],[12,3],[12,2],[12,1],[13,1],[13,2],[13,3],[13,4],[13,5]]


var corners = {
    'maxX': positions.filter(e => e[0] === Math.max(...positions.map(e => e[0]))),
    'minX': positions.filter(e => e[0] === Math.min(...positions.map(e => e[0]))),
    'maxY': positions.filter(e => e[1] === Math.max(...positions.map(e => e[1]))),
    'minY': positions.filter(e => e[1] === Math.min(...positions.map(e => e[1])))
  }
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(corners))
```

So the code above returns something like this:

```
{
 "maxX":[[13,1],[13,2],[13,3],[13,4],[13,5]], // x values are all 13 (max)
 "minX":[[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5]], // x values are all 6 (min)
 "maxY":[[6,5],[7,5],[9,5],[8,5],[10,5],[11,5],[12,5],[13,5]], // y values are all 5 (max)
 "minY":[[7,1],[6,1],[8,1],[9,1],[10,1],[11,1],[12,1],[13,1]] // y values are all 1 (min)
}
```

But how to get the right coordinates for each corner from the result above??
 I am absolutely clueless how to calculate the right ones, so I hope somebody can help me with my function..

Thanks in advance, jonas

Comment: Maybe the right one doesn't exist :-). When you rotate the square the corner will be place between line 1 and 2 (or 0 and 1). If you convert to your raster image to a vector geometry, you can calculate the exact position corner and afterwards find the "grid" which are the closest one.

Comment: Ok sound right... But tbh I have no clue how to convert the matrix into a vector geometry.. @AndersFinnJørgensen

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of the comment on the question. Convert to vector and find the "pixel" closest to the corners.

1. If you can identify the "1" that borders the square  (detect change from left to right and from top to bottom) and
2. Identify which "1" who belongs to which side of the square you can calculate the vector of each of the 4 borders using "minimum distance".

Afterwards you can calculate the intersection between the lines and you have the corners.

Minimum distance and intersection of lines are standard geometric operation, you can google. I cant remember them right know.

Answer (score -1):

```
function findExtremes( array ){
  let upRight = array[0],
        downRight = array[0],
        downLeft = array[0],
        upLeft = array[0];

  for(const [x,y] of array){
    if(x < downRight[0] || x === downRight[0] && y < downRight[1]) downRight = [x,y];
    if(x > upRight[0] || x === upRight[0] && y > upRight[1]) upRight = [x,y];

    if(y > upLeft[1] || y === upLeft[1] && x < upLeft[0]) upLeft = [x,y];
    if(y < downLeft[1] || y === downLeft[1] && x > downLeft[0]) downLeft = [x,y];
  }
  return {downRight, downLeft, upRight, upLeft};
}
```

The code works like this:

```
x < downRight[0]
```

This first part insures that we take the smallest x value. OR if

```
x === downRight[0]
```

weve got two minimal x values, we take

```
 y < downRight[1]
```

the one with the smaller y.

Comment: Hey Jonas, your solution looks absolutely fine. Thanks a lot. But I got an error, using a clockwise rotated matrix. Please look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukq6nm91/1/